# Create custom block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I created a 3d placeable item (a printer) with blockbench and I would like to make sure that I want to place it as if it were a player's head, i.e. that based on how you are turned, the item "looks" towards you, like I can do?

Not really a new object, even using a custommodeldata, as long as the result is as described above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.